# show tags for just one tumblr post on click (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tumblr

So I'm using jQuery to make these sliding tags that are shown on click on Tumblr, but my problem is that I don't know how to use the script so on click only the tags for that clicked-on post are shown. I'm using an icon font, there's one on every post, but when you click it all the tags for every post are shown.

```
.tags {display: none;}
```

```
<div class="post-controls">
        <a class="slide-tags"><span class="th th-bookmark-1"></span></a>
        <a href="{ReblogURL}" target="_blank"><span class="th th-reblog"></span></a>
        <a class="likeb" href="#">{LikeButton}<span class="actual-button"><span class="th th-heart-1-o"></span></span></a>
```

(So above the bookmark icon is what's clicked on to show the tags)
And below is the script itself.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".slide-tags").click(function() {
            $(".tags").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can go to the account [here](https://greenfig.tumblr.com) and actually click on it yourself and see what I mean (just click on the little bookmark next to the like and reblog buttons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a call to the current `$(this)` selector, while the rest will be removed from the display, using the `slideUp()` method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slide-tags").click(function () {
        $(".tags").slideUp();
        $(this).closest(".posts").find(".tags").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that but for some reason all it does is make the icon slide out on click?

Comment: Try the updated code. If you fail, then make a reproducible example.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I delete my answer for you and You can use `.not(` also .. you're right with using `.closest('.posts')` .. good luck :-)